# Vertex labels of graph: {index,weight}

Tags: graphs-and-networks, labeling

I would like to label vertices of a graph with an ordered pair of the vertex `Name` (or `Index`), and the `VertexWeight`. This seems natural:

```
g = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1}, VertexWeight -> {102, 103, 104},
  VertexLabels -> "Name"];
Graph[g,
 VertexLabels -> 
  Table[i -> {i, PropertyValue[{g, i}, VertexWeight]}, {i, 3}]]
```

But it overprints the vertex name and the vertex weight:

---

[image]

---

If I use instead `i/PropertyValue[{g, i}, VertexWeight]` I get a nice display
as fractions $\frac{1}{102}$ etc., but if there is cancellation this fails.

The documentation says

> Any expression can be used as a label.

so I should be able to accomplish this...

Comment: Use something like `Row[{i, "/", PropertyValue[{g, i}, VertexWeight]}]` instead

Comment: @CarlWoll: Brilliant! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SetProperty[g, {VertexLabels -> 
   Table[i -> Placed[{i, PropertyValue[{g, i}, VertexWeight]}, {Above, Below}], {i, 3}], 
  ImagePadding -> 20}]
```

or, slightly shorter,

```
 SetProperty[g, {VertexLabels -> 
  {v_:> Placed[{"Name", PropertyValue[{g, v}, VertexWeight]}, {Above, Below}]},
  ImagePadding -> 20}]
```

both give

[image]

Comment: Very nice! Thank you!

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke, my pleasure.