# Displaying weights and labels together at vertex: one version works, the other does not. Why?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I followed [Vertex labels of graph: {index,weight}](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/154513/vertex-labels-of-graph-index-weight) to display both vertex names and weights.

This works fine on the following code, but fails for the adaptation below it (where I try to place the results in rectangles for vertices.

Correct code:

```
temp = Graph[{x2 \[DirectedEdge] x1, x2 \[DirectedEdge] x4, 
   x5 \[DirectedEdge] x1, x5 \[DirectedEdge] x4, 
   x3 \[DirectedEdge] x2}, VertexShapeFunction -> "Square"]
temp = SetProperty[temp, 
  VertexCoordinates -> 
   ReflectionTransform[{0, -1}]@GraphEmbedding[temp]]
temp = SetProperty[temp, VertexWeight -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]
temp = SetProperty[
  temp, {VertexLabels -> {v_ :> 
      Placed[{"Name", 
        AnnotationValue[{temp, v}, VertexWeight]}, {Above, Below}]}, 
   ImagePadding -> 20}]
```

Code which fails (names are just displayed as the word Name.)

```
relations = {x2 -> x6, x2 -> x7, x5 -> x6, x5 -> x7, x3 -> x2}

    labeling[relations_, weights_] := 
 Graph[relations, 
  VertexCoordinates -> GraphEmbedding[Graph[relations]], 
  EdgeStyle -> Arrowheads[.04], 
  VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexSize -> 0.2, 
  VertexStyle -> White, VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[Red, 15], 
  EdgeStyle -> Black, VertexWeight -> weights, 
  VertexShapeFunction -> "Square"]

g = labeling[relations, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]

g = SetProperty[g, {VertexLabels -> Table[i -> 
 Placed[{i, PropertyValue[{g, i}, VertexWeight]}, {Above, 
   Below}], {i, 5}]}]
```

The following alternative fails too:

```
g = SetProperty[g, {VertexLabels -> {v_ :> Placed[{"Name", AnnotationValue[{g, v}, VertexWeight]}, {Above, 
    Below}]}}]
```

Both display a square to enter a vertex, with above it Name and below it a number (the correct weight). Instead of name, it should display the true labels, which are of the form x1 x2 x3 x4 or x5. I want to adjust matters to display both in the box via Center, but first need to figure out why the above code fails. It seems to follow the same syntax (?)

Comment: MMA version 12.1  The first "incorrect" code seems to work, but not the second

Comment: @DanielHuber I run 12.1. Bit confused at your answer. The first code listed, is listed as "correct". The second as "incorrect". Which is what I experience on 12.1. Do you mean there is a bug?

Comment: By first "incorrect" code I mean the second code. It gives labels "X2","X3"...However, the third code gives labels: "Name" and the number below.

Comment: Does the first "incorrect" code give you labels x2 etc and also weights? If not, it is still not correct since I need both.

Comment: No, it only gives the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** Replace `5` in the table iterator with `VertexList[g]`:

```
g = labeling[relations, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}];

g = SetProperty[g, {VertexLabels ->
   Table[i -> Placed[{i, PropertyValue[{g, i}, VertexWeight]}, {Above,  Below}],
     {i, VertexList[g]}]}]
```

[image]

Using

```
g = labeling[relations, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}];
g = SetProperty[g, {VertexLabels -> 
   Table[Placed[{i, PropertyValue[{g, i}, VertexWeight]}, {Above, Below}], 
     {i, VertexList[g]}]}]
```

gives the same picture.

**2.** Replace `"Name"` with `v` in the last code block:

```
g = labeling[relations, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}];

g = SetProperty[g, 
 {VertexLabels -> {v_ :> Placed[{v, AnnotationValue[{g, v}, VertexWeight]}, 
    {Above, Below}]}}]
```

[image]

You can also use

```
g = labeling[relations, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}];

AnnotationValue[g, VertexLabels] = {v_ :> 
  Placed[{v, AnnotationValue[{g, v}, VertexWeight]}, {Above, Below}]};

g
```

to get the same picture.

Comment: Thanks kglr for the detailed and helpful answer. I understand Name (for vertices) as a default label which Mathematica picks when a graph is specified via its edges. So using x2 -> x6 means that x2 and x6 will be used as names for these vertices (default labels). This remains that way until labels are changed by the coder. If this interpretation is correct, then I don't see in your answer point 2 why  v needs to be used rather than "Name". "Name worked fine in the first block of code I gave. Am I missing something?

Comment: I have another piece of code which worked fine with "Name", until I added VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[Red, 15] after which it failed. Then I replaced "Name" with v and it worked. Is this because ay change to VertexLabels (as in specifying style) means the labels are no longer "default labels" (Names) and hence the use of Name no longer makes sense? Or is this a bug? And if "Name" fails at times, should one always use v instead (so why use Name in the first place?)? I hope to get some clarity on this as it is tripping me up.

Comment: @Mike, it seems like a bug. A simpler example: `Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3}, 
 VertexLabels -> Placed[{"Name", "Index"}, {Before, After}]]` vs `Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3}, VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[Red, 16], 
 VertexLabels -> Placed[{"Name", "Index"}, {Before, After}]]`

Comment: yes indeed. Should I pass it on to support@wolfram.com
? Or do you prefer to do it? Your example is clear. @kglr

Comment: @Mike, please go ahead with the bug report.