# Displaying Vertex indices in different colour than vertices

Tags: graphs-and-networks

```
graph1 = SetProperty[graph1, VertexLabels -> Table[i -> Placed[{Style[i, Blue], 
    Style[PropertyValue[{graph1, i}, VertexIndex], Red]}, {Before, After}], 
{i, VertexList[graph1]}]]
```

does not display the indices in Red (gives an error).

is there a way to fix this?

This question is related to: [Graphs: colouring vertex weights differently from vertices](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/241683/graphs-colouring-vertex-weights-differently-from-vertices)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
graph1 = SetProperty[graph1,VertexLabels->Table[i->Placed[
  {Style[i,Blue], 
   Style[VertexIndex[graph1,i],Red]}
,{Before,After}],{i,VertexList[graph1]}]]
```

It turns out `PropertyValue` is being replaced by `AnnotationValue`.  Even so, calling `AnnotationKeys[{graph1,First@VertexList[graph1]}]` shows that a graph vertex has the following inbuilt annotations (formerly properties)

```
{VertexCoordinates,VertexShape,VertexShapeFunction,VertexSize,VertexStyle}
```

`VertexIndex` is a function on graphs just like `VertexList`, vertices do not store their index.